# Schema for Movies implementation date format ISO 8601

Tags: php, date, schema.org

I have this code where `$arrEventDetails` contains the release date of the movie. It contains format like `July 5, 2013`, I want the format to be `2013-05-07`.

```
<meta content=" . $arrEventDetails["ReleaseDate"] . " itemprop=\"datePublished\">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`July 5, 2013` is standard datetime format, so you can use DateTime or strtotime, like:

```
$dt = new DateTime($arrEventDetails["ReleaseDate"]);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

or:

```
echo date_create($arrEventDetails["ReleaseDate"])->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

or:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrEventDetails["ReleaseDate"]));
```

<sup>p.s. but since movies can be released before year 1970, I disadvice you the use of `strtotime` and `date` function, since they cannot handle years before 1970.</sup>

[Demo](https://eval.in/52194).